# I am facing issue in Flutter while run my application

Tags: java, android, firebase, flutter, android-studio

I am getting this error, After upgrading my all plugin in pubspec.yaml.This is first time happens i already add google gms service that is set 16 in build.gradle

```
E/AndroidRuntime(15809): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isAtLeastR()Z in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/PlatformVersion; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.util.PlatformVersion' appears in /data/app/~~JfP3wXyoXYoELpSoGWT6BA==/com.sales.track-rakLI-SsZSlGKP6o0EIh4Q==/base.apk)
E/AndroidRuntime(15809):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.<init>(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:8)
E/AndroidRuntime(15809):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.<init>(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:22)
E/AndroidRuntime(15809):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.<init>(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:23)
E/AndroidRuntime(15809):    at com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient.<init>(Unknown Source:8)
E/AndroidRuntime(15809):    at com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(Unknown Source:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(15809):    at proto.inventa.cct.com.inventalibrary.InventaSdk.initialize(Unknown Source:70)
E/AndroidRuntime(15809):    at proto.inventa.cct.com.inventalibrary.InventaSdk.initializeInventaSdk(Unknown Source:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(15809):    at com.spicemoney.spiceimpact.spice_impact.DistrictApplications.onCreate(DistrictApplications.java:46)
E/AndroidRuntime(15809):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1192)
E/AndroidRuntime(15809):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7283)
E/AndroidRuntime(15809):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:303)
E/AndroidRuntime(15809):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2183)
E/AndroidRuntime(15809):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(15809):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:261)
E/AndroidRuntime(15809):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8279)
E/AndroidRuntime(15809):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(15809):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
E/AndroidRuntime(15809):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
```

Comment: We can't help you with just a a stack trace.  Can you post the minimal code that demonstrates this error?

Answer (score 1):

There is the solution you need to reduce the dependency version google-sign plugin inside build.gradle.

Our basic object is to change support number as per other dependencies in gms service based

Convert this to

> implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.0.1')

This like that

> implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.+'){
> exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-v4'
> }

Comment: This doesn't appear to be related to the stack trace you posted above.  Can you say how it is related?

Comment: If this is additional information about the problem you should edit it into the question rather than posting it as an answer.  If you did intend this to be an answer, than please say more about how it solves the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).